# $http.post can't send data as string, but json works

Tags: angularjs, http

I am making a call from `angularjs` to `nodejs`. When I do a `$http.post`, I am able to send the data if its json but not as string, I am unable to understand where I am going wrong! Here is the relevant angularjs code : 
`$scope.categoriesSend` is a string

This code works like a charm :

```
$scope.checkCicks = function() {
    var dict = $scope.selectedCategories;
    console.log($scope.selectedCategories);
    $scope.categoriesSend = "";
    for (var eachkey in dict) {
        console.log(eachkey, dict[eachkey]);
        if (dict[eachkey] === true) {
            var fields = eachkey.split('--');
            console.log(fields[0])
            if ($scope.categoriesSend != "") {
                $scope.categoriesSend = $scope.categoriesSend.concat("\n");
            }
            $scope.categoriesSend = $scope.categoriesSend.concat(fields[0]);
        }
    }
    console.log("Check");
    console.log($scope.categoriesSend);
    console.log("Check");
    // $scope.dataToSend = {data : "yes"}
    $scope.dataToSend = {
        data: $scope.categoriesSend
    }
    $http.post('/writeCategories', $scope.dataToSend).then(function(response) {
        console.log("Done");
    });
}
```

But, if I try to send the string as it is - it says `the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`

```
$http.post('/writeCategories', $scope.categoriesSend).then(function(response) {
    console.log("Done");
});
```

This is the `nodejs` backend code

```
writeCategories: function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Here");
        console.log(req.body.data);

        var data = req.body.data;
        var newPath = path.join("public", "process", "categories.txt");
        fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
        res.json({status: "done"});
    },
```

Comment: `$http.post`  [accepts a string or an object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-arguments) as a `data` parameter

Comment: you need to add $scope.dataToSend instead of $scope.categoriesSend....
$http.post('/writeCategories', $scope.dataToSend).then(function(response){
                console.log("Done");
            });

Comment: @ParthRaval - ya, that works, that is what my doubt is, if i send json, that is working, but it is not working if I send the string.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey - exactly what i was thinking, but still it is not accepting the string, hence the doubt

Comment: @Tarun which language you are using as backend?

Comment: @ParthRaval - nodejs

Comment: @Tarun you should probably post backend code as well (it fails to accept strings from a post request)

Comment: then node js only takes json request parameters.